# Catch link preview request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, outlook, slack

I have an application when kind of links are generated which can be clicked only once. For next click link is disabled.

When the link is sent via Outlook or Slack or some other tool the request comes without even clicking it. I've found that this is Link Previes request to get some information. Is there any chance to catch those request and avoid link deactivating on such requests?

Biggest problem is that I can't test it in local environment so can't check how the request looks like because Outlook can't send preview link to localhost. I've also found that there is a chance in Outlook to disable link preview request but it doesn't resolve that problem. I need to catch that on backend site somehow.

Any ideas?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-link-preview-in-outlook-com-and-outlook-on-the-web-ebbfd8ce-d38e-40ef-bb8c-a5362e881163

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much you can do about that.

Do not use links as one-time actions. Add an extra step to your page that requires the user to explicitly click a link or a button.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will add some button which will start the process to avoid such a things.